# Annotation processing never be invoked

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, annotations, annotation-processing

Im working on a little library that should generate java code from Annotations.

```
public class MyAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

/**
 * This suffix will be appended on every {@link OrmAble}
 */
public static final String CLASS_SUFFIX = "Helper";

private Elements elementUtils;
private Types typeUtils;
private Filer filer;

@Override
public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment env) {
    super.init(env);

    elementUtils = env.getElementUtils();
    typeUtils = env.getTypeUtils();
    filer = env.getFiler();
}

@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
        RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

    System.out.println("Start AnnotationProcessing");

    for (Element elem : roundEnv
            .getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)) {

        if (elem instanceof TypeElement)
            createCode((TypeElement) elem);

    }

    // no further processing of this annotation type
        return true;
    }

private void createCode(TypeElement typeElement) {

        // Write the view injector class.
        try {

            JavaFileObject jfo = filer.createSourceFile(
                    getPackageName(typeElement) + typeElement.getSimpleName()
                            + CLASS_SUFFIX, typeElement);

            Writer writer = jfo.openWriter();
            brewJavaCode(writer, typeElement);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            error(typeElement, "Unable to write injector for type %s: %s",
                    typeElement, e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            error(typeElement, "Class "
                    + typeElement.getQualifiedName().toString() + " not found");
        }
    }
}
```

I use maven to build it but the annotation and have written some Unit Test that has some classes that are annotated with MyAnnotation.

My pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>

                 <executions>
                      <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <goals><goal>compile</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                        </configuration>
                      </execution>
                      <execution>
                        <id>default-test-compile</id>
                        <goals><goal>testCompile</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <annotationProcessors>
                            <annotationProcessor>com.example.MyAnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                          </annotationProcessors>
                        </configuration>
                      </execution>
                 </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I have also tried to run the tests with the annotated classes in eclipse. I have generated a jar from my library and have set it as AnnotationProcessor in eclipse. But the annotation Processing is never be executed.

As far as I know the generated class files should be placed in target/ right or where does the generated java file will be stored?

```
JavaFileObject jfo = filer.createSourceFile(
                    getPackageName(typeElement) + typeElement.getSimpleName()
                            + CLASS_SUFFIX, typeElement);
```

Any suggestion what could be wrong?

Comment: Is your annotation processor annotated with @SupportedAnnotationTypes and @SupportedSourceVersion?

Comment: Yes: @SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.example.MyAnnotation")

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old thread but for future readers please ensure you have these items setup:

1. The `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` that contains the fully qualified name of the AP is registered under `META-INF/services`
2. You override the function `getSupportedAnnotationTypes()` which should return a list of the desired `Annotations` to be processed.
3. At least one class in your `classPath` is using one of the desired annotations. This is due to `Java compiler` optimisation in a way that the annotation processors are only invoked if **AND ONLY IF** they should be invoked, hence a class is annotated with one of the desired annotations.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define all of your processors into a text file whose name starts with javax.annotation.processing.Processor.

If you want to see a working example , please have a look here.
https://github.com/jsaurav/Code-Generation

Comment: yes, i found some description: "Include in the Jar file a directory META-INF/services. Include in the directory a file named javax.annotation.processing.Processor". However it still nor work. The  generated jar file contains the META-INF/service/javax.annotation.processing.Processor file . Even if I compile a Test class that is annotated with javac my annotation processor does not start.

Comment: Ru sure u have any class annotated with MyAnnotation ?